# ASP.Net and HTML5

Tags: html

I need to develop a web application, i have two choices

1. mvc3 straight forward implementation
2. using HTML5

i want to know whether HTML5 can be used as part of .net web application architecture or not?

Reasons:

there is no official support of HTML5 server controls like 
Now IE 9 was launched but how good it supports HTML5

I found in internet that there is installation for HTML5 helper, but how reliabale it is?

I need guidance on the HTML5 and .net and if any tutorials in this combination.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft always argument that HTML5 isn't fully finished. Then ASP.NET cannot be totally rewriten to follow it. Makes some sense, but...

You can do it by yourself: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/11/building-an-html5-app-with-asp-net.aspx.

But I realy believe that ASP.NET MVC is more flexible to it task.

Answer (score 1):

Standards are based on implementation, not invention. If Microsoft wants to wait till HTML5 spec is finished, they will be waiting a long time. Meanwhile, modern browsers have implemented large portions of the spec and are moving forward.

With that in mind, how can one expect ASP.NET to contain elements of HTML5 and related technologies if Microsoft doesn't believe in its usage right now? In our small business, this is the reason we would never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty open-ended.  What do you want out of HTML5?  If you're just looking for controls, you run into a roadblock that ASP.Net web forms won't render the new HTML 5 input types with placeholders and custom keyboards like URL Input, Email input canvas, etc.  I made an [open-source project](http://html5asp.sourceforge.net/) to make these plug and play with Web Forms.

If you're looking for other parts of the spec, pay special attention to whether or not the markup "fails gracefully".  If you can optimize the experience with HTML5, but still keep a baseline quality for older browsers, I say go for it!